# How to get hibernation working on Sony Vaio X with Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: hibernate, vaio, sony

i am trying hard to get hibernation mode working on a Sony Vaio X Laptop.
I already tried what [this guy is advising](https://web.archive.org/web/20130804040815/http://westhoffswelt.de:80/blog/0041_sony_vaio_x_ubuntu_installation_experience.html), but it wasn't helping.

Maybe someone else had the same problem and could solve it somehow?

Cheers,
Luki

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link with instructions on How To Enable Hibernate [LINK](http://theubuntudocumentary.wordpress.com/2012/07/04/how-to-enable-hibernate-ubuntu-12-04/)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advice. The problem is, that `pm-hibernate` seems to wake up the computer immediately.
After showing some lines like:
`(9795.534485) drm_sysfs_suspend` or
`[drm:psb_xhw_add] *ERROR* No Xpsb 3D extension available`

I think it deals something with the Intel GMA500 card. Anyone an idea?

Cheers